# What is the role of runtime-gdb.py in Go language?

Tags: python, go

I just created my first ["Hello World"](https://gobyexample.com/hello-world) program in Go language, built it and created the binary file. Upon inspecting the binary, I came across reference to this [python script](https://golang.org/src/runtime/runtime-gdb.py) inside the binary file.

The description of this script reads

> This script is loaded by GDB when it finds a .debug_gdb_scripts
>   section in the compiled binary. The [68]l linkers emit this with a
>   path to this file based on the path to the runtime package.

I don't understand the meaning of this clearly. So, what is **[runtime-gdb.py](https://golang.org/src/runtime/runtime-gdb.py)** and how is it related to Go language?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use the [gdb](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger to debug your program, loading that script improves its features for working with Go programs, such as being able to look at the values inside of maps and slices (instead of seeing them as opaque pointers) and being able to list and inspect goroutines (instead of native threads). gdb uses Python for extensions.

Comment: Is there a flag for building the binary in debug mode? I don't remember specifying any option related to debugging. I mean to ask if inclusion of this script can be made optional.

Comment: @Beginner: it's not included in the binary, it's only referenced by name in the DWARF info. You can optionally disable DWARF generation with the `-w` link flag, but there's generally no reason to do so.

Comment: @JimB - Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 2):

gdb is scriptable in python. This is a script for golang support.